# The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup. AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

When I use this code on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider 
     android:authorities="android.androidcustom.quicknotesprovider"
     android:name=".QuickNotesProvider" >="" <="" pre="">  
</provider>
```

I have this error, how could I fix?

The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.   AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: what is those strange characters at the end of line?!!

Comment: If `="" <="" pre="">` is the content of the provider tag, you have to escape the brackets e.g. like this: `&gt;%lt;`

Answer (score 4):

Remove the syntax errors from the end, like so:

```
<provider 
    android:authorities="android.androidcustom.quicknotesprovider"
    android:name=".QuickNotesProvider" >
```

I assume that you are closing this tag as well:

```
</provider>
```

---

If you are using Eclipse sometimes miscellaneous characters will appear at the end of your line when you use the auto-complete features. (Sometimes these "bonus" characters aren't even displayed, which can be frustrating!)